# JPA @AutoGenerated on primary key uses parent sequence/auto incerement for nested entity

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

in my Spring Boot application I'm trying to save an Entity with a few nested Entities that have a one-to-many relationship. I'm using JPA and Hibernate to save them to a MySQL database.

On the primary keys, I am using `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)` on a `Long` to automatically create values for new entities. This worked for some time, however recently I'm getting an error when trying to save the entity:

```
java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '282' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

This is what my entities look like:

**Question.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "question")
public class Question {

    private Long id;
    private List<Answer> answers;
    // other fields

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Long getId() { return id; }

    public void setId(Long id) { this.id = id; }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "question", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    public List<Answer> getAnswers() { return answers; }

    public void setAnswers(List<Answer> answers) { this.answers = answers; }
}
```

**Answer.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "answer")
public class Answer {

    private Long id;
    private Question question;
    // other fields

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Long getId() { return id; }

    public void setId(Long id) { this.id = id; }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "question_id")
    public Question getQuestion() { return question; }

    public void setQuestion(Question question) { this.question = question; }
}
```

Repositories are simply:

```
public interface QuestionRepository extends JpaRepository<Question, Long>{ ... }
```

Now let's say I am adding a new Question via a web form, including 4 Answers. When calling the repository simply like:

```
questionRepository.save(question);
```

After some investigation, it appears that Hibernate is using the auto increment value from the `question` table for the `answers` entities, which doesn't work because it already exist.

Trace output log:

```
Hibernate: insert into question (id) values (?)
2019-08-31 18:47:49.652 TRACE 11516 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [6] as [BIGINT] - [281]

Hibernate: insert into answer (question_id, id) values (?, ?)
2019-08-31 18:47:49.688 TRACE 11516 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [3] as [BIGINT] - [281]
2019-08-31 18:47:49.688 TRACE 11516 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [4] as [BIGINT] - [282]

2019-08-31 18:47:49.746  WARN 11516 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1062, SQLState: 23000
2019-08-31 18:47:49.746 ERROR 11516 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Duplicate entry '282' for key 'PRIMARY'
2019-08-31 18:47:49.748 ERROR 11516 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.i.ExceptionMapperStandardImpl        : HHH000346: Error during managed flush [org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement]
2019-08-31 18:47:49.847 ERROR 11516 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [PRIMARY]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement] with root cause

java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '282' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

I've verified that the `auto_increment` value on the `answer` table is 581.

What could be the cause of this? Is there property/configuration I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since MySQL doesn't support sequences natively so this issue might occur when @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) is used.

Use the below workaround for id generation.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(
    strategy= GenerationType.AUTO,
    generator="native"
)
@GenericGenerator(
    name = "native",
    strategy = "native"
)
```

Please refer https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11014 for further details.

You can also refer ::: https://vladmihalcea.com/why-should-not-use-the-auto-jpa-generationtype-with-mysql-and-hibernate/

Comment: You're right: I upgraded from Hibernate 4 to 5 and in logs I see the `SELECT next_val as id_val ...` queries. Adding your suggestion solves the problem. One question you might know: I see that `id` is now not send as part of the insert query, so does MySQL itself figure out what the next id should be?

Comment: Thanks you so much - this answer was incredibly helpful!!